# Binary Search algorithm random array

Tags: search, binary, fortran

I don't understand why the recursive function always gives me zero result, even if I put values inside the array.
it seems that size (a) == 0

```fortran
recursive function binarySearch_R (a, value) result (bsresult)
real, intent(in) :: a(6), value
integer          :: bsresult, mid

mid = size(a)/2 + 1
if (size(a) == 0) then
    bsresult = 0        ! not found
else if (a(mid) > value) then
    bsresult= binarySearch_R(a(:mid-1), value)
else if (a(mid) < value) then
    bsresult = binarySearch_R(a(mid+1:), value)
    if (bsresult /= 0) then
        bsresult = mid + bsresult
    end if
else
    bsresult = mid      ! SUCCESS!!
end if
end function binarySearch_R

program hji
read*, a
read*, value
print*, binarySearch_R
end program hji
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is really far too much wrong with your code that you would benefit more from a good language tutorial than asking a question here. However, to improve your question you can add `implicit none` to your main program and fix the resulting errors. There is an issue with the function, but the fundamental problems with the main program obscure that.

Answer (score 3):

## Chapter 1: The dangers of implicit typing

The first thing I strongly recommend you do is to include the line

```
implicit none
```

after the `program` line. This will suppress implicit typing, and the resulting errors will give you some useful insight into what is happening.

If you did that, you'd get an error message:

```
$ gfortran -o binsearch binsearch.f90
binsearch.f90:23:12:

     read*, a
            1
Error: Symbol ‘a’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
binsearch.f90:27:25:

     print*,binarySearch_R
                     1
Error: Symbol ‘binarysearch_r’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
binsearch.f90:24:16:

     read*, value
            1
Error: Symbol ‘value’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

It doesn't matter that `a`, `value`, and `binarySearch_R` were defined in the function. As the function is not part of the `program` block, the program doesn't know what these are.

With implicit typing active, it simply assumed that all three are simple `real` variables. (The type depends on the first letter of the variable name, i through n are `integer`, everything else is `real`)

Because this implicit typing can so easily hide coding errors, it's strongly, *strongly* suggested to always switch it off.

Which also means that we have to declare the variables `a` and `value` in the program:

```
program hji
    implicit none
    real :: a(6), value
    ...
end program hji
```

## Chapter 2: How to introduce a function to the program?

So how does the program get access to the function? There are four ways:

1. The best way: Use a module

   ```
    module mod_binsearch
        implicit none
    contains
        recursive function binarySearch_R (a, value) result (bsresult)
            ...
        end function binarySearch_R
    end module mod_binsearch

    program hji
        use mod_binsearch
        implicit none
        real :: a(6), value
        ...
    end program hji
   ```

   Note that the `use` statement has to be before the `implicit none`.
   This method leaves the function separate, but callable.
   It automatically checks that the parameters (that's something we'll be coming to in a bit) are correct.
2. Have the function contained in the program.

   Between the final line of code of the program and the `end program` statement, add the keyword `contains`, followed by the function code (everything from `recursive function ...` to `end function ...`).

   This is the quick-and-dirty method. You have to be careful with this method as the function will automatically have access to the program's variables unless there's a new variable with that name declared inside the function.
3. The convoluted way: Interfaces

   Create an interface block in the declaration section of your program's source code,
   and repeat the interface information in there.

   This still allows the compiler to check whether the function is invoked correctly, but it's up to you to ensure that this interface block is correct and matches the actual implementation.
4. The really, *really* ugly way: Declare it like a variable, invoke it like a function.

   Please don't do that.

## Chapter 3: Calling a function

When you call a function, you have to use the parentheses and give it all the parameters that it expects. In your case, you need to type

```
print *, binarySearch_r(a, value)
```

## Chapter 4: Dynamic arrays as dummy parameters

In the successive recursive calls to the function, the array gets smaller and smaller.
But the dummy parameter is always the same size (6). Not only will this interfere with your algorithm, but this can also lead to dangerously undefined memory access.

Fortunately, specially for `intent(in)` dummy parameters, you can use dynamic arrays:

```
recursive function binarySearch_R(a, value)
    real, intent(in) :: a(:), value
```

The single colon tells the compiler to expect a one-dimensional array, but not the length of it. Since you're already using `size(a)`, it should automatically work.

Comment: What does "Declare it as a variable, invoke it like a function." mean?  If you mean `real binarySearch` then that's still a function declaration not a variable declaration.

Comment: I have changed the wording to 'like a variable' -- Technically people might stumble across this, but I don't want anyone to actually do this.

Comment: @francescalus You're right, the statement about padding was incorrect and misleading. I've rephrased this now, I hope it's correct now.

Comment: It may be interesting to implement the algorithm to get the columns in which the search key is present even more than once, e.g. if there are two equal numbers in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, but not an answer (*and to any Fortran experts reading this, yes, there are one or two places where I gloss over some details because I think they are unimportant at this stage*) ...

The way the code is written does not allow the compiler to help you. As far as the compiler is concerned there is no connection between the function and the program.  As far as the program is concerned `a` is, because you haven't told the compiler otherwise, assumed to be a real scalar value.  The `a` in the program is not the same thing as the `a` in the function - there is no connection between the function and the program.

The same is true for `value`.

The same is true for `binarysearch_r` - and if you don't believe this delete the function definition from the source code and recompile the program.

So, what must you do to fix the code ?

First step: modify your source code so that it looks like this:

```
program hji
... program code goes here ...
contains
    recursive function binarySearch_R (a, value) result (bsresult)
    ... function code goes here ...
    end function binarySearch_R
end program hji
```

This first step allows the compiler to see the connection between the program and the function.

Second step: insert the line `implicit none` immediately after the line `program hji`.  This second step allows the compiler to spot any errors you make with the types (real or integer, etc) and ranks (scalar, array, etc) of the variables you declare.

Third step: recompile and start dealing with the errors the compiler identifies.  One of them will be that you do not pass the arguments to the function so the line

```
print*, binarySearch_R
```

in the program will have to change to

```
print*, binarySearch_R(a, value)
```

Comment: I approve of your glossing over. I've answered myself, and was getting too much into the weeds, had to trim out a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's exhausting trimming all the weeds, and a lot of it is probably over OP's current-Fortran-head anyway.